# Как отправить Buffer (image) на другой сервер

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, fileupload, request

Имеется сервер Node JS - expressJS, который получает картинку из POST пост запроса. Далее необходимо эту картинку отправить на другой сервер (микросервис).

Картинку я успешно получаю, а вот дальше отправить ее не получается.

Далее небольшой код для теста, в котором первое АПИ получает картинку из браузера и тут же ее отправляет на второе АПИ.

---

package.json dependencies

```js
"dependencies": {
    "lodash": "latest",
    "nunjucks": "latest",
    "redis": "latest",
    "connect-redis": "latest",
    "express": "latest",
    "express-session": "latest",
    "cookie-parser": "latest",
    "body-parser": "latest",
    "query-string": "latest",
    "multer": "latest",
    "request": "latest"
}
```

---

index.js

```js
const http = require('http');
const request = require('request');
const express = require('express');
const multer = require('multer');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const upload = multer();

var app = express(),
    server = http.createServer(app);

/**
 * Set body parser
 */
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/test1', upload.single('file'), (req, req) {
  console.log('test1 file ->',req.file.buffer); // Here Buffer

  request.post(
    {
      url: 'http://localhost:3000/test2',
      formData: {
        avatar: req.file.buffer
      }
    },
    (err, httpResponse, body) => {
      console.log();
      console.log('test1 err', err);   // No errors
      console.log('test1 body', body); // {success: true}
      console.log();
    }
  );

  res.json({success: true});
});

app.post('/test2', upload.single('avatar'), (req, req) {
  console.log('test2 file ->', req.file);     // undefined
  console.log('test2 avatar ->', req.avatar); // undefined
  console.log('test2 files ->', req.files);   // undefined
  console.log('test2 body ->', req.body);     // {}

  res.json({success: true});
});

/**
 * Run server
 */
server.listen(3000);
```

Для отправки POST запроса на /test2 использую [npm package request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request)
Во втором запросе вижу, что ничего не пришло. Если кто сталкивался, укажите как правильно это сделать. У меня пока варианты закончились.

PS вариант сохранить файл на диск, а потом считать его fs.createReadStream не красиво.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25344879/uploading-file-using-post-request-in-node-js

Comment: но правильнее сразу сабмитить файл на 3002, например, проксируя туда "upload"-запросы фронтендом. или, на худой конец, для коммуникации между 3000 и 3002 использовать webdav вместо post-запроса

Comment: Да спасибо! Я видел этот пост. С него и попал на документацию. И делал по нет. Только вот не работало. Немного изменил код и взлетело. Проксировать не вариант, так как перед загрузкой итд идут проверки доступа итд. И переносить логику в другое место - не вариант.

Answer (score 0):

Первоначально я делал по документации. Но @norborner посоветовал внимательнее читать. В итоге изменил код отправки на иной код

```js
let r = request.post('http://test.loc:3000/test2', (err, httpResponse, body) => {
  console.log();
  console.log('err', err);
  console.log('body', body);
  console.log();

  res.json({success: true});
});

let form = r.form();
 
form.append('avatar', req.file.buffer, {
  filename: req.file.originalname,
  encoding: req.file.encoding,
  mimetype: req.file.mimetype,
  size: req.file.size
});
```

После чего все успешно отправилось. Спасибо за помощь!