# JavaScript отправка Buffer с фото

Tags: javascript, node.js

Для того что бы отправить фото в node-js я использую вот этот код:

```
    ...

    request.post({
    url: 'https://host.net',
    data: {
        note: 'Photo',
        file: fs.createReadStream('path/to/b101.jpg'),
        filename: 't100.jpg',
    },
}, function(error, response, body) {
    console.log("BODY: " + body);
    console.log("RESPONSE: " + JSON.stringify(response) );
});

...
```

Но у меня очень часто случается что фото находятся в буффере, без локального хранения, вида:

```
var photoBuffer = Buffer.from([255,216,255,224,0,16,74,70,73,70,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,255,254,0,59,67,82,69,65,84 ...]);
```

Как мне переконвертировать Buffer-to-Stream и отправить этот стрим или просто буфер на сервер?

В данный момент у меня получается либо пустой стрим либо еррор еще до оправки. В случае с пустым стримом, я вижу что мсдж доходит до сервера, тк. в респонсе код=200.

Может какие то ограничения еще и со стороны сервера имеются?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для того чтобы конвертировать `Buffer` в `Stream` есть несколько способов, один из них это использование готовых пакетов типа `buffer-to-stream`, второй - использование нативного `stream` пакета.

```
const { Readable } = require('stream');

// Ваш буфер
const buffer = Buffer.from([255,216,255,224,0,16,74,70,73,70,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,255,254,0,59,67,82,69,65,84...]);
const readable = new Readable();

readable.push(buffer);
readable.push(null); // Конец записи данных

readable.pipe(
    request.post({ ... })
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Нашел ответ вот [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/597829/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-buffer-image-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80?rq=1)

```
form.append('avatar', req.file.buffer, {
  filename: req.file.originalname,
  encoding: req.file.encoding,
  mimetype: req.file.mimetype,
  size: req.file.size
});
```